# map iterable values to keys using Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I've the following data saved in a `JavaPairRDD`.

**Starting Data**

```
key(nodeName)    PointsTo                         1/n     n

node1           [node2,node3,node4]               0.33    3 
node2           [node1,node5]                     0.50    2 
node3           [node1,node2,node4,node5]         0.25    4 
node4           [node1,node2]                     0.50    2 
node5           [node2,node3,node4]               0.33    3 


key(nodeName)   PointsTo        1/n        n

node2           node1           0.33       3 
node3           node1           0.33       3 
node4           node1           0.33       3

node1           node2           0.50       2 
node5           node2           0.50       2 

node1           node3           0.25       4 
node2           node3           0.25       4 
node4           node3           0.25       4 
node5           node3           0.25       4 

node1           node4           0.50       2 
node2           node4           0.50       2 

node2           node5           0.33       3 
node3           node5           0.33       3 
node4           node5           0.33       3
```

The JavaPairRDD looks like this.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<String>,Double,Double>>
```

Where `String = key(nodeName)` while Tuple3 have `PointsTo, 1/n and n values` respectively.

Now I want to perform 2 steps.

**Step 1:**

```
key(nodeName)    PointsTo                         1/n     n

node1           [node2,node3,node4]               0.33    3 
node2           [node1,node3,node4,node5]         0.50    2 
node3           [node1,node5]                     0.25    4 
node4           [node1,node3,node5]               0.50    2 
node5           [node2,node3]                     0.33    3
```

**Step 2:**

```
key(nodeName)    PointsTo                         1/n     n

node1           [0.11,0.14,0.32]                  0.33    3 
node2           [0.92,0.14,0.32,0.67]             0.50    2 
node3           [0.92,0.67]                       0.25    4 
node4           [0.92,0.14,0.67]                  0.50    2 
node5           [0.11,0.14]                       0.33    3
```

It will be much easier if I explain it w.r.t a single node. So lets take `node4`. `node4` is appearing in `PointsTo` where the `keys` are `node1,node3,node5`. Hence we simply update the `PointsTo` where `key=node4` to now have `node1,node3,node5`.

**Note that the values in the `1/n and n` columns are the same w.r.t the keys.**

In `step 2` we simply replace the `nodeNames` with their respective `1/n` values.

So the final JavaPairRDD will look like this.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<Double>,Double,Double>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt on this:

- from `JavaPairRDD` get reference data  (data1, data2: see output for details) and stored in `Map`
- create function to scan input data and replaces with new `Iterable<String>` values using reference data 2 `Map` in new `Iterable<String>` : see `getStep1Data()`
- create function to scan `Iterable<String> PointsTo1` from source RDD and replaces with its `1/n` values using reference `Map` in new `Iterable<Double>`: see `getPointsToN()`

source:

```
public class SparkTest {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local");
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);

        PairFunction<String, String,Tuple3<Iterable<String>,Double,Double>> keyData =
                new PairFunction<String,String,Tuple3<Iterable<String>,Double,Double>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            public Tuple2<String, Tuple3<Iterable<String>, Double, Double>> call(String line) throws Exception {    
                return new Tuple2(line.split("\\|")[0], 
                        new Tuple3(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\|")[1].split(",")),
                                Double.parseDouble(line.split("\\|")[2]),Double.parseDouble(line.split("\\|")[3])));
            }
        };

        System.out.println(" --- Input Data ---"); //Data to start with
        JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<String>,Double,Double>> masterData = 
                sc.textFile("Data\\node.txt", 1).toJavaRDD().mapToPair(keyData);
        masterData.foreach(line -> System.out.println(line));

        Map<String,Double> refData1 = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        Map<String,Iterable<String>> refData2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Iterable<String>>();
        masterData.collect().forEach(line -> {refData1.put(line._1, line._2._2()); refData2.put(line._1, line._2._1());});
        System.out.println(" --- Referacne Data 1-- "); //stored referance Data node and its 1/n value
        for(String k: refData1.keySet())System.out.println(k + " --> " + refData1.get(k));

        System.out.println(" --- Referacne Data 2-- "); //stored referance Data node and its 1/n value
        for(String k: refData2.keySet()) System.out.println(k + " --> " + refData2.get(k));

        System.out.println(" ---  Data in Step 1 --- ");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<String>,Double,Double>> step1RDD =
            masterData.mapToPair(line ->new Tuple2(line._1, new Tuple3(getStep1Data(line._1,refData2), line._2._2(), line._2._3())));

        step1RDD.foreach(line -> System.out.println(line)); 

        System.out.println(" --- Data in Step 2 --- ");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<Double>,Double,Double>> step2RDD =
                step1RDD.mapToPair(line ->new Tuple2(line._1, new Tuple3(getPointsToN(refData1, line._2._1()), line._2._2(), line._2._3())));

        step2RDD.foreach(line -> System.out.println(line)); 
    }
    // get 1/n values from referance Data for pointsTo in new list
    public static Iterable<Double> getPointsToN(Map<String, Double> refData, Iterable<String> pointsTo){
        ArrayList<Double> n1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(String node: pointsTo)
            if(refData.containsKey(node))
                n1.add(refData.get(node)); 
        return n1;
    }
    // get node values from referance Data 2 for pointsTo in new list
        public static Iterable<String> getStep1Data(String node,Map<String, Iterable<String>> refData2){
            ArrayList<String> n1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String n: refData2.keySet())
             refData2.get(n).forEach(element -> {if(element.equals(node)) n1.add(n);});             
            return n1;
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just one thing. I am unable to retrieve the data in `JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Iterable<Double>,Double,Double>> finalRDD`, the line which you commented out for foreach loop. This gives me a `typemismatch error i.e you cannot convert JavaRDD<object> to the above datatype`. Do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: You still need to write `PairFunction` for that to store as `JavaPairRDD` - so `forEach` part should be replaced by `mapToPair(<pairfunction>)`

Comment: see update - I converted to `JavaPairRDD` - upvote it if you learn something new from this : )

Comment: I just realized one major issue. You didn't actually performed step 1. Can you please re-read the question.

Comment: The starting data should not be the one in `step 1` but the one which is mentioned above at the starting of the question.

Comment: Ok will get back to you in evening (EST)

Comment: hey ronak this looks good. I am wondering, would it be more efficient if instead of implementing the reference functions with for loops, we directly use `map reduce` to map the node names in `pointsTo` column as `keys` and their respective keys as values. Than perform `reduceByKey` on them. This will give us the same result. But would it be more efficient ?

Comment: sure if we can use `mapreduce` its even better, either way we'll have to scan the entire `pointsTo` column for each `node` (key) - but with large data mapreduce will be efficient - if you try `mapreduce` way, let me know the results...

Comment: Yes I am trying. Actually I've a huge dataset so that's what I am trying to achieve. Thanks...

Comment: if you provide source data (file) format - I can also try on my end... in you question you provided input data with transformation already performed `JavaPairRDD` (to start with)

Comment: Can I send you an email ? What's your email ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133817/discussion-between-ronak-patel-and-mj1992).